# Getting 'Multiple Controllers Found' Error

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I am getting this runtime error from a new project.

I actually don't have any duplicate controller names. They all reside in my Controller folder and have unique names. I am not sure why I'm getting this.

I also did follow the suggestion to add a namespaces parameter even if they were all located in one folder.

> Multiple types were found that match the controller named 'Channel'.
>
> This can happen if the route that services this request
>   ('{controller}/{action}/{id}') does not specify namespaces to search
>   for a controller that matches the request.
>
> If this is the case,
>   register this route by calling an overload of the 'MapRoute' method
>   that takes a 'namespaces' parameter.
>
> The request for 'Channel' has
>   found the following matching controllers:
>
> MyProject.Controllers.ChannelController
>
> MyProject.Controllers.ChannelController

Comment: Are you sure you didn't copy your `ChannelController.cs` file into another file but forgot to rename the new file's class controller?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It turns out I had another DLL in the same folder. I renamed my project, and the older DLL was there with exactly the same controllers.